# Chrome OS: how to enable direct SFTP access in the Files app / Pixelbook Review

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ftp, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, ftp-client

An article on Chrome OS that I read here:
    https://medium.com/@JamesCridland/review-five-months-with-a-chromebook-for-web-development-writing-and-more-8adf36b4a061

says:
"Update: Above, I mention that I use SSH and vi to do my programming work. And I did. Except I don’t any more. It turns out that one of the newer updates added direct SFTP access into the Files app (the equivalent of Explorer or Finder), so that my development box appears simply as another drive on my Chromebook. And Caret is an excellent programmer’s editor. So now I have a proper programmer’s editor (as well as the SSH terminal I need to put those changes live)."

Ok. But, when I go into Chrome OS's files app, the apparent way 'mount' my equiv of his
'development box' is via 'add new services', which is launching a webstore-app named 'SFTP' (whose icon is a blue folder outline with "SFTP" on it).  i,e.:
    https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sftp-file-system/gbheifiifcfekkamhepkeogobihicgmn?hl=en

(My equiv of his 'development box' I'm assuming to be my web-server at bluehost.com, where I currently use Firefox's FireFTP extension, on Win-10.)

I can't get this 3-stars webstore 'SFTP' app (authored by someone from Japan) to authenticate me into my bluehost acc't.  So, now I'm wondering whether
this 'SFTP' app is even the right thing to have installed, due to all the one- and two-star showstopper reviews.  One typical review by a guy named Tim says:

"It's a nice try, but I really wish someone who knows what they're doing would make this service. It looks like it works but if you drill down more than a few folders deep on the remote filesystem, operations slow to a crawl."

Similarly, the two clients ('sFTP client' and 'sFTP client Lite) also have such low ratings, that my gut says that Google has failed to deliver a robust web-developer infrastructure.

Come on Google...you need to implement this stuff under your own logo.

Am I missing something???

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo

Answer (score 8):

Probably should advertise this functionality better :), but the [Secure Shell extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd) supports mounting via SFTP so it will appear in the Files app.

Steps to use:

1. Install [Secure Shell Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd).
2. Launch the extension (look for it in the bar to the right of the omnibox/browser URL bar -- it'll have a black terminal icon).
3. Enter the connection details to create a new profile.
4. Give it a description like "user@foo.com".
5. Instead of clicking "Connect" in the bottom right, click "Mount".
6. Authenticate with the server (keys/pass/whatever).
7. Once it finishes, it'll now be visible in the Files app.

If you suspend/resume the system or otherwise logout/reboot, you'll need to relaunch Secure Shell, select the saved profile, and then click "Mount" again.  We probably should make this a bit smoother, but that's how it works currently.

Comment: Is there some step missing?  If I hit connect then I get password prompt and regular login.  If I hit SFTP Mount then it says connecting but never prompts for a password, and nothing is mounted. All settings at defaults.

Comment: Ah you're hitting a bug in the current release.  Fix should be out this weekend.  Assuming you only have a password prompt, you might be able to work around it by blindly typing your password and hit enter.

Comment: No update seen yet, but blind typing does the trick and sftp access works well in the Files app.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Linux(beta) on your chromebook. Then you can do whatever you want like on others linux machine.

A simple sftp connection command

`sftp [user@]host`

Answer (score 0):

Enable linux and mount with sshfs

`sudo apt install sshfs`

then

`sshfs -o reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3 user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/remotedir localdir`

or with key auth

`sshfs -o reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/remotedir localdir`

These will reconnect after resuming from sleep

Answer (score -1):

No, not an answer yet...just more wishlist stuff:

Ok, more recent info about the Firefox browser's "FireFTP" addon:

It no longer works on the (new) std Firefox browser, as of a couple of
weeks ago when version 57.0 was released.  (No biggie tho...a goggle revealed
a new-to-me browser called 'Waterfox' and it nicely supports FireFTP and the
other addons that Firefox dropped support for.)

So a bit more research yielded only yet more 'mumble-mode' confusion: it revealed that FireFTP is open source...located here:
    https://github.com/mimecuvalo/fireftp
(So I submitted a new 'issue' there and asked about porting it to Chrome.)

I'm desperate, and recently test-drove Google's new Pixelbook.
(Sigh...nothing inspirational came of that...I give it one-thumb-down rating.
Here's my notes from that experience:

------------ Review notes of Pixelbook: ----------------------

Google didn’t think to include a USB-C to USB-A adapter. (A $2 item. e.g.)
    [https://www.amazon.com/Remax-USB3-1-Female-Adapter-Silver/dp/B01MCSRSKN/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MCSRSKN)

That was my 'showstopper'...like a few other reviewers said...it's not well
thought out / matured.  To me it feels more like a gimmick, than a product.
At a minimum, it rates my newest hashtag: #NRFPT (not ready for prime time).

I found no obvious way to disable the touchpad, when using a mouse.
In fact, no other reviewers expressed interest in using a mouse. (???)

Lastly, my favorite kind of Android apps are 'widgets', and I see no signs
that it has occurred to Google to allow Chrome-OS's desktop/background to
host any widgets.

---

Ok, I'm still in mumble-mode...and still in search of a FTP/SFTP GUI client for
the Chrome browser / Chrome-OS that is the quality of FireFTP.